# Compress PDF of images without downsampling

Tags: bash, pdf, compression

How can I compress a 300 DPI PDF of images without downsampling? e.g. without using `gs` or alternative to convert it into a 150 DPI PDF?

I'm looking for something like https://docupub.com/pdfcompress/ but with Linux batch functionality.

Comment: So you don't want to change the data of the images themselves? I.e. only make the PDF smaller without touching the images?

Comment: No, I'm happy lossy-compressing the images, but I don't want to reduce their pixel count.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick's `convert` will do just this:

```
convert -density 300 input.pdf -quality 30 output.pdf
```

Where 300 is the input DPI and 30 is the output quality, in percent.

No need for piping commands together or using the much more lossy `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen`.